# Windows Start menu is listing files without folders, in Win 10

Tags: wix, windows-10

I have a WiX created installer that sets up the start menu with a fair number of sub folders.  It's a product for developers, so there are demos for different versions of Visual Studio, and it's helpful to have them grouped by VS version.

In Windows 10 the items in the Start menu are listed flatly, no folder hierarchy.

Is there a way to make my folders appear in the Win 10 start menu, or do I need to approach my start menu differently?

```
    <DirectoryRef Id="ProgramMenuDir">
        <Component Id="ProgramMenuShortcutsComponent" Guid="*">
            <!-- create folders -->
            <CreateFolder Directory="ProgramMenuDir" />
            <CreateFolder Directory="ProgramMenuProductSubFolderDemos" />
            <CreateFolder Directory="ProgramMenuProductSubFolderCSDemos" />
            <CreateFolder Directory="ProgramMenuProductSubFolderVBDemos" />
```

and many more.  It's a complete mess in Win 10, as all the items from all the folders are listed in one long list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 10 supports only single-level sub-menus in start menu (which may make some sense - according to some latest UI designer findings, hierarchical menus suck). So if you have multi-level sub-folders, they are ignored, and their content is just put under the top folder. The outcome is that probably you'll need to think of a different grouping for your shortcuts.